# Convergence of a specific series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

The assignment that I am having trouble with is as follows:

a) Use the fact that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n^3\left(\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{6}$ to show that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac 1n-\sin\left(\frac 1n\right)\right)$$

converges.

b) Determine the radius of convergence of the power series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac 1n-\sin\left(\frac 1n\right)\right)x^n$$

I am having real trouble with computing the limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left\lvert\frac 1n-\sin\left(\frac 1n\right)\right\rvert^{\frac1n}=r^{-1}$$ Here r is the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the first part (to use [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) then) was given [in this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/315161) 
(indeed $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}-\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\frac{1}{n^3}}$ is given to be $\frac{1}{6}$), the second: $\frac{1}{n}=x$
(that's an only a variable change for the limit, no relation to the $x$ in the question),
$$\begin{align*}\lim\limits_{x\to 0}|x-\sin x|^x&=
\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left|\frac{x-\sin x}{x^3}\right|^x\cdot x^{3x}\\
&=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\left|\frac{1}{6}\right|^x\cdot e^{3x\ln x}=1
\end{align*}$$
Where $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} x \ln x$ [is known](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052932/limit-of-x-lnx) to be $0$.

Comment: Thank you for linking that page. I am assuming that by the comparison test 1/n - sin(1/n) < 1/(6n^3) therefore 1/n - sin(1/n) converges. Can you explain why that inequality holds?

Comment: Please see the edits. Questions welcome, if any.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to help. It is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin(\frac 1n)=\frac 1n -\frac{1}{6n^3}(1+\epsilon(n))$$
with
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\epsilon(n)=0$$
thus

$$u_n= \frac 1n-\sin(\frac 1n)\sim \frac{1}{6n^3}$$

the two  series  $\sum u_n x^n$ and $ \sum \frac{1}{n^3} x^n$ will have the same radius of convergence $(R=1)$.

Comment: What does the notation "~" mean? That they are almost equal for n large?

Comment: @Tom They are equivalent. If one goes to L, the other also goes to L.  for example $\sin(x)\sim x (x\to 0)$.